# Finding the latest updated value only from table

Tags: php, mysql

Hey guys i have a table structure like

```
 CREATE TABLE CUSTOMERS(
   ID   INT              NOT NULL,
   NAME VARCHAR (20)     NOT NULL,
   AGE  INT              NOT NULL,
   ADDRESS  CHAR (25) ,
   SALARY   DECIMAL (18, 2), 
   PRIMARY KEY (ID)
)

INSERT INTO  CUSTOMERS (ID,NAME,AGE,ADDRESS,SALARY)
VALUES (1,'aff',2,3,5)
VALUES (2,'afff',1,31,52)


update CUSTOMERS
set NAME = 'somenewname'
where age = 1;
```

I just want to get output as `'somename'`

I have tried creating a column `updatedtime` with `timestamp` and used query like

```
SELECT * FROM CUSTOMERS ORDER BY updatetime DESC LIMIT 1;
```

But this one shows the whole values ..

I just need only the updated value 'somenewname` as output.

I have also tried using `triggers and functions` but it didnt helped..

Please help me with a solution..I will accept it as an answer if it helps me ..remember i want an output as a single value like `somenewname`.

Thanx

The trigger which i have used

```
CREATE TRIGGER getrandom 
AFTER UPDATE ON CUSTOMERS
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
UPDATE CUSTOMERS 
SET NAME = 'anewname'
WHERE ADDRESS = 3;
END;
```

Comment: And where you have `updatetime` column in your table?

Comment: In your example update statement potentially many rows will be updated in one transaction. Which row should be considered the most recently updated one? There are a lot of edge cases at play here this is an example of just one of them.

Comment: The solution to this problem is a trigger, so please post the trigger you used (which you say didn't work) and folks here will help you with a solution.

Comment: 18,2? Can I have a job?

Comment: @ShrinathKuppa please help me .i have edited my question as you said

Comment: @panther i have tried it but it didnt work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't you try to **SELECT** only the `name`-column

```
SELECT name FROM CUSTOMERS ORDER BY updatetime DESC LIMIT 1; //outputs the name
```

instead of the whole result

```
SELECT * FROM CUSTOMERS ORDER BY updatetime DESC LIMIT 1;
```

Your **UPDATE** statement should look like

```
update CUSTOMERS
set NAME = 'somenewname',
updatetime = now()
where age = 1;
```

---

Now a example of how to get only the `name` if tables are joined.

```
SELECT c.name FROM CUSTOMERS as c INNER JOIN orders as o c.id=o.id  ORDER BY c.updatetime DESC LIMIT 1;
```

Comment: see as i told i just ned only the updated value ,,i just only need output as somenewname

Comment: The first SQL statement should output the name only. What do you get by that statement?

Comment: see i told you i have updated my table ..on column name with a value somenewname ,i just only want output as somenewname